# Network meltdown - No properties on the connections

Tags: windows-7, networking

I have bumped into an major network connection issue, all network devices are unable to establish a network connection and I have no idea how to solve it.

Have tried to reinstall the drivers, removed all virtual devices and different types of connection. I don't believe it is the drivers though since I have tried the following different types of connections:

- Ethernet
- Wireless
- 3G
- Virtual Connection

All got the same issue, and all the types of connections are working for other PC's in the same network.

Have tried to do a system restore on Windows 7 but the restore point did not fix the issue. Also tried Safe mode with network but same issue there.

Here is a image on how the problem presents itself:

[image: Image of the error]

Anyone got a clue how to proceed in order to fix this **without** reinstalling Windows 7?

Comment: Do the event logs show any failures/error messages?  Can you ping localhost/127.0.0.1? Does the network troubleshooter report anything?

Comment: Can you manually assign an IP address that is available on the local network and make any connection/PING other hosts?

Comment: ping 127.0.0.1 works, ping localhost also works but resolves to IPv6 address. WMI throws an error in the eventviewer that it fails with a query, but that is it.

Comment: ping to our gateway 192.168.10.1 result in:
Unable to send ping signal. General failure.

Comment: What does ipconfig show?

Comment: It just say disconnected - Even though the GUI status says that it is connected with 100Mbit/s.

Comment: Which antivirus do you have running?

Comment: No antivirus or firewall is currently active, not even the Windows ones.

Comment: Reset the Winsock stack. Google should direct you to the KB article.

Comment: It might that your restore point doesn't go back far enough but the problem arose?

Answer (score 0):

You mention in the comments that "ping localhost" resolves into an IPv6 address, so I am wondering if your internal network does not completely support IPv6. The weak spot may be the router or another component, but the simplest solution would be to try and turn of IPv6 on all computers and in the router.

This is described for Windows in the article
[How To Disable IPv6 In Windows 7](http://www.addictivetips.com/windows-tips/how-to-disable-ipv6-in-windows-7/).

A more in-depth article published by Microsoft might also help :
[How to disable certain Internet Protocol version 6 (IPv6) components in Windows Vista, Windows 7, and Windows Server 2008](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/929852)

Answer (score -1):

There is a Service that if it was turned off , it can disable all that stuff.
In control pannel | administrative tools | Computer management , Click on Services and applications, and then click on services.

Or WinKey-R and type services.msc

or in search just type services.msc and hit enter.

in there check for the 4 "network . . ." services.  (I dont know the one that would have your symptoms yet)

---

> fix this without reinstalling Windows 7

Yes, have a full Image backup of your operating system, that is created say weekly, and Recovered if nessisary outside of the operating system.  A backup program like Acronis for example, that runs off of a CD or USB stick, and does not run that system, or depend or rely on that system.

I know this does not fix todays problem, but it will fix more problems in less time than anything in the system does.  I have had the same problem your showing in XP once,  spent some time redoing everything, doing discovery.

I Uninstalled  the networking portions of the OS, Then Re-installed the networking portions, using add and remove windows programs (now called On and Off) and never figured it out. With windows 7 you really cant even remove networking components to reinstall them.

In 3 minutes I fixed it by booting to a CD, recovering my full image backup of the OS I had saved.  Less time than it took me to write this. :-)

If you secure your Functional OS with an Image of the partition, Then store your important data on a seperate data disk or partition, away from the system. Then set your e-mail to stay on the server for a bit longer than usual, the loss from retracting the system back a week is minimal.

Somebody had to say it. Might as well be me.